# How to stop slapd within Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, debian, openldap, dockerfile

I try to build my own Docker container with `slapd` and `Dockerfile`.

Installation of `slapd` is OK and then I need to stop `slapd` in order to add a custom database.
For that I need to run `slapadd` command on a non running `slapd`. Nevertheless `RUN pkill slapd` produces the following error:

```
Step 7 : RUN service slapd start ; ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f xxx.ldif
---> Using cache
---> 53e1e1a59517
Step 8 : RUN pkill slapd
---> Running in efc0058a4bfe
The command '/bin/sh -c pkill slapd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Do you know why and how I can stop properly `slapd` with `Dockefile`?

Comment: You don't want to `RUN service slapd start`. You want to `CMD /usr/sbin/slapd` (or whatever). `RUN` is meant for provisioning the container, `CMD` is the command that runs in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting your slapd operations over multiple `RUN` directives: that is not practical, as each `RUN` will create an intermediate container, and commit that container as an intermediate image.

It is best to group all your operation in one script, that you `COPY` first in your image, and then `RUN` that script.
That way, inside one intermediate container, you can start/stop slapd, add your ldif files, do other tests, *before* the intermediate container stops and is committed as a new intermediate image.